# Can Pages export .doc document to .xml?

Tags: pages, xml, macos

Can I do this using Pages? It's basically a simple table made in MS Office Word (.doc) which I need to convert to xml / html, insert some html input blocks (there are cells which are left empty for data input). I remember doing this with MS Office Word (the exporting), but it was a long time ago, I lost the file and now I need it again, but I have the original .doc one on my mail, so I just need to export it once again. So is it possible do this with pages or do I need to do it on someone's PC (I don't have Office for OSX)?

Comment: What exact XML do you need - or is it just into something that can be viewed on the web i.e. HTML?

Comment: Any XML that can be displayed by a web browser or HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear the Pages can export to XML (here's the exported formats: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4641). I did come across a website (http://www.office-converter.com/Convert-to-XML) that converts .doc files to .xml files. I tested it against a .doc file I exported to .xml from Word and the documents look the same.